# Найти на странице все теги <a> и удалить их, а содержимое (то что между <a></a>) должно остаться

Tags: javascript, html

Мне нужно найти все теги . На html странице, сами теги все удалить, а содержимое оставить без изменения. Как я понимаю можно найти родителя каждого тега  и удалить дочерний тег. Я могу получить массив всех узлов  DOM и пройтись по ним в цикле, но как мне в этом случае получить родителя? Или я не в ту степь полез вообще?

Comment: можно взять весь html код через document.body.innerHTML. Применить к нему допустим replaceAll с регулярным выражением для нужных вам тегов, и вставить обратно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach( link => {
  link.outerHTML = link.innerHTML;
});
```

```html
<a href="#">123</a>
<div>
  <a href="#">456 <span>789</span></a>
</div>
<p>ABC</p>
<p>
  <a href="#">DEF<br>XYZ</a>
</p>
```

Учтите только, что в данном способе смена HTML создаёт новые элементы, а не перемещает старые. Если старые элементы имеют какие-то свойства, установленные через JS, то они будут потеряны. Например `div.myProperty = 123;` удалится.

Этого недостатка нет в следующем коде, перемещающим элементы наружу из ссылок:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach( link => {
  Array.from(link.childNodes).forEach( childNode => link.before(childNode) );
  link.remove();
});
```

```html
<a href="#">123</a>
<div>
  <a href="#">456 <span>789</span></a>
</div>
<p>ABC</p>
<p>
  <a href="#">DEF<br>XYZ</a>
</p>
```